# Google OAuth 2.0 not detects restored credentials

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I accidentally deleted my Firebase project. As it turned out this project was linked with Google Cloud project which was responsible for OAuth 2.0 credentials and consent screen information. Later I restored the Firebase project, the Google Cloud project and the OAuth 2.0 credentials. But my Sign in with Google still not working, it gives me "Access blocked: Authorization Error. The OAuth client was deleted. Error 401: deleted_client" error. I thought that Google needs some time to detect all the restored things, but a two days already passed since restoration and I'm still getting same error.

Do I need to perform some additional actions after restoration to make it work or wait more time? Or restored credentials are not valid anymore and I should generate new ones?

I also tried to change some information in OAuth consent screen and now in Google Cloud console I can't submit OAuth consent screen for the verification. I'm getting this error "com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Brand state must be enabled for developer verification review."

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for 4 days and after I've messaged Google Support about this problem my old credentials started to work. Though I don't know which action resulted in problem solve.